# Find an equation of the form $H(x,y)=c$ satisfied by the trajectories of the system $x'=-x, y'=y+\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given a hint to use the thorem of exact first order ODEs so I started by saying

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+\sin x}{-x}
$$.

Let $M=-x$ and $N=y+\sin x$.  Then $M_x=-1$ and $N_y=1$.
However for it to be an exact ODE I want $M_x=N_y$.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I have also tried to find a function $Ψ$ such that $Ψ_x(x,y)=-x$ and $Ψ_y=y+sinx$ and I can't get this to work either

Comment: I take it $x'$ means $dx/dt$. What if you first solve $x'=-x$, then plug that solution into the second equation and try to solve it?

Comment: I think you have the condition backwards: You need $\Psi_x(x,y)=y'$ and $\Psi_y(x,y)=-x'$, up to a possible integrating factor (though you don't need it here).

Answer (score 1):

As Gerry Myerson commented, considering the system
$$x'=-x \qquad \qquad y'=y+\sin(x)$$ with $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ solve the first equation
$$x'=-x \implies x=c_1 e^{-t}$$ Plug in the second equation
$$y'=y+\sin(c_1 e^{-t})$$ which solves using the method of variation of parameters 
$$y=c_2e^t+\frac{e^t \cos(c_1  e^{-t})}{c_1}$$ Now, from $x$ $$t=-\log(x)+\log(c_1)\implies y=\frac {c_1c_2+\cos(x)}{x}=\frac {c_3+\cos(x)}{x}$$

For sure, as you wrote, you could have obtained the solution working directly the equation $$y'=-\frac{y+\sin x}{x}$$ Let $$y=\frac z x \implies y'=\frac{x z'-z}{x^2} \implies z'+\sin(x)=0\implies z=\cos(x)+c_3$$

So, by the end $xy -\cos(x)=c_3$ seems to be  $H(x,y)=c$.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the hint consequently to the end, the exact differential equation in its usual normal form is
$$
(y+\sin(x))\,dx+x\,dy=0,
$$
that is, $M=y+\sin x$ and $N=x$ so that indeed $M_y=1=N_x$ and a direct integration is possible. One should directly detect
$$
d(xy)=y\,dx+x\,dy
$$
as part of the expression, so that the first integral is indeed
$$
H(x,y)=xy-\cos x.
$$